# How to solve second order ODE $X''(x) + 2αX'(x) + c^2n^2π^2X(x) =0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, boundary-value-problem

I'm a little stuck on solving this ODE  $$T''(t) + 2αT'(t) + c^2n^2π^2T(t) =0$$

**Note:** We are given that $~α<cπ~$ and the initial condition  $~T'(0) = 0~$.
I need to find the general solution and using the conditions the specific solution to $~T_n$.

This is what I've managed to do so far :

I found the characteristic equation to be $~r^2 +2αr + c^2n^2π^2=0~$ and by completing the square I got $~(r+α)^2= α^2-c^2n^2π^2~$.

Since $~α<cπ~$, I got $~ r= -α +/- \sqrt(α^2-c^2n^2π^2)~$. Therefore the general solution for $~T~$ is given by

$$T_n(t) = A_n ~e^{-αt}~\cos(\sqrt{c^2n^2π^2-α^2~}~t~) + B_ne^{-αt}~\sin(\sqrt{c^2n^2π^2-α^2~}~t~)$$ Am I correct?

Would really appreciate the help.

Edit: Corrected $~T(t)~$.

Comment: All you can do here is to simply write $\sqrt{\alpha^2 - c^2n^2\pi^2} = \pm \sqrt{c^2n^2\pi^2 - \alpha^2}i$, you can't be more explicit than this really.

Comment: Thanks, so would the general solution just be $T_n(t) = A_n e^{-αt}cos(\sqrt(α^2-c^2n^2π^2) + B_ne^{-αt}sin(\sqrt(α^2-c^2n^2π^2)$ ?

Comment: For complex roots $r = p\pm qi$, the general solution is $T(t) = e^{pt}\left[C_1\cos(qt) + C_2\sin(qt)\right]$. So you should have $\cos\left(\sqrt{c^2n^2\pi^2 - \alpha^2}t\right)$ instead (and similarly for $\sin(\dots\dots)$).

Comment: @neels you have to differentiate full $X(t)$ to incorporate $x'(0)=0$. See my answer. Also, the argument of sin and cos should be $\sqrt{n^2\pi^2c^2-\alpha^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X(x)=e^{mx}$ the, you get the characteristic equation for $m$ as
$$ m^2+ 2 \alpha m+ c^2 n^2 \pi^2=0.$$ This gives $$m_1,m_2=-\alpha\pm \sqrt{\alpha^2-c^2n^2\pi^2}.$$ So the general solution is 
$$X(x)=C_1 e^{m_1 x}+ C_2 e^{m_2 x}~~~(1).$$ If $\alpha< cn \pi$.Then
$m_1,m_2=-\alpha\pm i \beta.$ Then
$$X(x)= e^{-\alpha x}[ D_1 \sin \beta x+ D_2 \cos \beta x]~~~(2)$$ By putting the condition that $X'(0)=0,$ we get 
$$X(x)=De^{-\alpha x}[\alpha  \sin \beta x +  \beta \cos \beta x],~~ \beta =\sqrt{c^2n^2\pi^2-\alpha^2}~~~(3).$$
In your solution $t$ is missing in the arguments of sin and cos.Also the condition that $X'(0=0$ has not been caried out..

Comment: Thanks. See edit

Comment: What did you get for X'(x)?

Comment: @Neels I got $()= {−}[1 \sin+2 \cos]$, please omit $C_1$ iit is a typo. I am going to edit it.